# MySQL Grouping Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a number of tables in my database.

Table: ObjectToPerson

For example if I had a number of entries below in the database:

```
+----+------------+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
| Id | WeekNumber |    Date    | PersonId | ObjectId | ObjectTypeId |
+----+------------+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
|  1 |          1 | 2015-11-04 |        1 |        1 |            1 |
|  2 |          1 | 2015-11-04 |        1 |        3 |            2 |
|  3 |          1 | 2015-11-04 |        2 |        2 |            1 |
|  4 |          1 | 2015-11-04 |        2 |        4 |            2 |
+----+------------+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
```

I am wanting to return the results back as two lines as follows:

```
+------+------------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| Week |    Date    | PersonId | ObjectId(ObjectTypeId = 1) | ObjectId(ObjectTypeId = 2) |
+------+------------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|    1 | 2015-11-04 |        1 |                          1 |                          3 |
|    1 | 2015-11-04 |        2 |                          2 |                          4 |
+------+------------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

I am thinking of some sort of Group By query but I just can't seem to get it right.

```
Select * From ObjectToPerson
Left Join Objects O On O.Id = ObjectToPerson.ObjectId And ObjectToPerson.ObjectTypeId = 1
Left Join Objects O On O.Id = ObjectToPerson.ObjectId And ObjectToPerson.ObjectTypeId = 2
```

Can someone explain how I would get to this please?

Comment: Not sure what your intent is.. in your example.. should the value in the column of ObjectId(ObjectTypeId = 2) for the first row be 3? instead of 2?

Comment: Apologies Dave, yes it should have been 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CASE to only select the ObjectId if the type is correct for the column, then use MAX/GROUP BY to group the result into a single row per person/week/date.

```
SELECT WeekNumber week, date, personid, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN ObjectTypeId=1 THEN ObjectId END) Type1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ObjectTypeId=2 THEN ObjectId END) Type2
  FROM ObjectToPerson
  GROUP BY week, date, personid
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1cff/3)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want two joins, you want a `WHERE` clause;

```
SELECT * FROM ObjectToPerson
LEFT JOIN Objects O ON O.Id = ObjectToPerson.ObjectId
WHERE ObjectToPerson.ObjectTypeId IN(1,2)
```